# Spring Data Couchbase @CreatedDate not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm using Spring boot with spring data couchbase.
I've added two fields for **createdDate** and **lastModifiedDate** with `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate` annotations in **Movie** Document.

**lastModifiedDate** works great but **createdDate** is always null.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Document
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @NonNull
    @Getter
    private String id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NonNull
    private String title;

    @Getter
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @Getter
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;
}
```

I've also added a configuration for `@EnableCouchbaseAuditing`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseAuditing
public class AuditConfiguration {
}
```

Movie Repository:

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "movie")
public interface MovieRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Movie, String> {

    Collection<Movie> findByTitle(String title);

    Collection<Movie> findByTitleLike(String title);

    Collection<Movie> findByTitleStartingWith(String title);

}
```

application.yml for reference:

```
spring:
  couchbase:
    bootstrap-hosts: localhost
    bucket:
      name: movie
  data:
    couchbase:
      auto-index: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing), in order to distinguish between a creation and an update, `spring-data-couchbase` needs a `@Version` annotated attribute in the entity class

Answer (score 0):

If anyone lands here ... I had an issue with the `createdDate` not being populated even though I followed the [spring-data-couchbase documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase). I followed the process of [creating immutable objects](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.property-population) for my Document and [Auditing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing). The cause was the field annotated with `@CreatedDate` was `final` (I used lombok `@Value`). I had to make it non-final (`@NonFinal` using Lombok) for it to finally work.

Comment: can u please tell me what was the change for createdDate field , i am also facing same issue of null .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I updated my application with spring boot and spring-boot-couchbase, I also face a similar issue. `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate` annotations can't update the date time itself in real-time.
Finally, it was solved when I added `@EnableCouchbaseAuditing` in the Application.

here is the pom update

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And the Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCouchbaseAuditing
public class Application {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```